# Cannot add distribution provisioning profile to Xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, provisioning-profile

I'm trying to distribute my Phonegap app on the iTunes. I have done this before successfully before but I have since changed to a new Mac. I'm using Xcode 5.0.2.

I have created development and distribution certificates. I then created an App ID, entering the Bundle ID under "Explicit App ID".

I then created a development provisioning profile for the app, choosing the correct App I.D., the iOS Development certificate, my device, giving the profile a name and clicking "generate".  I download it and double click to add to xcode. The xcode organiser opens and I see it added under my device provisioning profiles. I can then successfully run the app on my physical device.

Now I want to distribute it. I created a new provisioning profle, selecting "App Store" under Distribution, selecting the correct App I.D., the iOS Distribution certificate, and clicking "generate". When I double click the downloaded file, the organiser in xcode opens, but the distribution provisioning profile doesn't under the device provisioning profiles. When I click the + button to add the profile, I cannot select the Distribution provisioning profile, but I can select the Development provisioning profile: 
[image]

I have no idea why this is. I tried closing down and opening xcode, to no avail. I tried waiting a few hours. Again, it didnt work.

I then try to distribute my app by creating an archive. First I go to build settings > code signing and choose iPhone Distribution:

[image]

I then select my physical device and choose Product > Archive. I get the error:

```
No matching provisioning profiles found
None of the valid provisioning profiles include the device Belgian Iphone  (identifier: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx).  
Xcode can resolve this issue by downloading a new provisioning profile from the Member Center.
```

I click "Fix Issue" and end up with the error:

```
There was an error generating the team provisioning profile for AppID 'FT49U8Q9JE'.
```

The AppID given here is different to the prefix in App ID's in the developer portal. I don't know if it should be the same. Any suggestion? I have spent 3 days on this problem and as stated above, I had no issues on my previous mac (which I no longer have)!

Comment: you need to go dev portal and create a distribution profile for your app. ( name it after the name of the app if you want) download that and then double click on the file that is downloaded. it will automatically integrate with Xcode. then you will be able to see it and select it. this step is new. you need to create a distribution profile for every app now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something that got me recently was having to actually set the provisioning profile in the build settings[image]

Comment: I cannot choose the distribution profile from here because it does not show up as I cannot add it to xcode...

Comment: Have you tried Xcode > Preferences > Accounts > View Details - does the provisioning profile appear if you perform a refresh?

Comment: Yes it does actually appear in that list, but not under the device provisioning profiles...

Comment: suddenly it appeared under Provision Profile! So now I can create an archive. Thanks, will mark as correct