# Provisionning Profile still doesn't appear in Organizer

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I have the same problem as in [Cannot add distribution provisioning profile to Xcode 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783628/cannot-add-distribution-provisioning-profile-to-xcode-5)

I have refreshed Xcode Preferences Account and provisioning profiles then appear there but going back to Organizer, drag and drop provisionning profile file or using "+" button still doesn't work with no error message :(

So what I can do now ? I tried to close and reopen Xcode again but nothing changed.

Comment: What does it mean: "still doesn't work with no error message". Why did you decide that it doesn't work if there are no any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult find the problem without informations.
I suggest you to **start from scratch** to create a new certificate, **following the Apple Guide**.